# Send array of photos as JSON from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Longtime listener, first time caller :-)

I'm new to nodejs and to javascript and am struggling to wrap my head around the event & callback model.

My goal:  return array of photos (name, width, height, exif data) as JSON.  This is needed so that my app can then work its magic with the JSON array of pics.

Situation:  my code seems to work except that things are not running the in the order that I'd like.  I'm expecting to stream the JSON for each picture to the HTTP Response but my console logging reveals that things aren't in desired sequence and I suspect that res.end() is being called too early.  This means that my web request gets nothing in the response.

The relevant code:

```
fs.readdir(readDir, function (err, files) {
    var picsInfo;
    if (err) res.writeHead(500, err.message);
    else if (!files.length) res.writeHead(404);
    else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            files.forEach(function(file) {
        console.log('easyimage');
        easyimg.info(readDir + '/' + file, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(stdout));
            res.write(JSON.stringify(stdout));
        });
        });
    }
    res.end();
});
```

The output I see in my console reveals things are not in order (I'm expecting each photo to be sent to res):

```
easyimage
easyimage
easyimage
easyimage
easyimage
easyimage
easyimage
easyimage
easyimage
easyimage  
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"933","height":"1400","size":"532365B","name":"6.jpg"}
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"1400","height":"933","size":"318134B","name":"3.jpg"}
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"1400","height":"933","size":"310927B","name":"10.jpg"}
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"933","height":"1400","size":"258928B","name":"1.jpg"}
req.method=GET...
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"1400","height":"928","size":"384475B","name":"7.jpg"}
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"933","height":"1400","size":"469711B","name":"4.jpg"}
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"1400","height":"933","size":"392666B","name":"2.jpg"}
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"1400","height":"933","size":"354468B","name":"5.jpg"}
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"1400","height":"933","size":"438143B","name":"9.jpg"}
{"type":"JPEG","depth":"8","width":"933","height":"1400","size":"304939B","name":"8.jpg"}
```

I've tried using some examples I've found (e.g. http://blog.nakedjavascript.com/going-evented-with-nodejs but think that I'm just missing something key in terms of the eventing/callback model.  Any pointers or help would be much appreciated.  Also, if my approach here (i.e. sending JSON to res, etc.) is dumb or sub-optimal I'd also love some tips on what might be best.

Thanks in advance for any pointers & help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I can't run the code, so it might need some tweaks:

```
fs.readdir(readDir, function(err, files) {
    var filesPath = files.map(function(file) {
      return readDir + '/' + file;
    });

    async.map(filesPath, easyimg.info, function(err, json) {
        if(err)
            return res.end(500, err.message);

        res.end(JSON.stringify(json));
    });
});
```

What was wrong with your code ?

- As I said earlier, `res.end()` was called immediately because `easyimg.info` answers asynchronously.
- You call `easyimg.info` for each file, but there is no guarantee that the response will arrive in order. See the wonderful [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) lib (`npm install async`).
- When you return an error with a callback, make sure you return as well. Always use the pattern `return cb(err)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, Laurent!  This helped but it's still not working as I would expect.  I made the tweak you suggested and I got one photo's JSON to output to the browser (i.e. the request).  However, the other photos' JSON are not coming through.  This seems to me that res.end() is still being called too soon (i.e. after the first photo's JSON is sent to the response).

Comment: OK, I see the problem, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I will dig into this later tonight and will let you know how it goes.  At first glance I'm not following how I would continue to use the easyimgae package (https://github.com/hacksparrow/node-easyimage) in your code.  Do I need to make that into a separate function?  Also, do I need to write HTTP headers prior to this code?

Comment: Feel free to ask for clarifications. The gist is that [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) manipulates functions like `iterator(item, callback)` with `callback(err, result)`. Since easyimg follows this standard, it can be passed to `async.map` without defining a new function. Unless told otherwise, node will reply with code 200 and default headers.

Comment: `res.write` doesn't automatically stringify objects into JSON; are you thinking of Express's `res.send`?

Comment: ebohlman is correct.  using res.end(json) causes the server to crash with "TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer".  I've got it working by changing this to res.end(JSON.stringify(json)).  Thanks to you both!